# How use BETWEEN operator in CASE without start and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

have start and end dates:

```
   oa.entity_created            oa.lagg

  id 1|  start |2022-07-20     end |2022-08-15
  id 2|  start |2022-06-15     end |2022-08-09
  id 3|  start |2022-08-12     end |blank
```

How to count between this dates without start date and end date, like this

```
   oa.entity_created            oa.lagg

   id 1| start |2022-07-21     end |2022-08-14
   id 2| start |2022-06-16     end |2022-08-08
   id 3| start |2022-08-13     end |blank
```

If blank count until `current_date`

```
count(case when (oa.entity_created < cred.entity_created and oa.lagg > cred.entity_created) then 1 end)
```

doesn't work correctly

Comment: If you compare with a NULL value (`< NULL`), the result is never TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct interpret the *blank* value in the predicate (I assume this is a `null` value) use COALESCE with the *default* value, which is the `CURRENT_DATE` in your case.

```
  coalesce(oa.lagg,CURRENT_DATE)
```

So for example to get all rows from the table that *match*  the date of `2022-08-14` use the following predicate (see the `WHERE` clause, rest is sample data).

```
select * from (
values
(date'2022-07-20',date'2022-08-15'),
(date'2022-06-15',date'2022-08-09'),
(date'2022-08-12',null)
) oa(entity_created,lagg)
where oa.entity_created < DATE'2022-08-14' and coalesce(oa.lagg,CURRENT_DATE) >  DATE'2022-08-14'

entity_created|lagg      |
--------------+----------+
    2022-07-20|2022-08-15|
    2022-08-12|          |
```

Adapt this predicate in your `CASE` statement accordingly.